# 7z: What *does* the -r flag do?

Tags: 7-zip

The man page for `7z` simply says

> Do not use "-r" because this flag does not do what you think.

The only documentation I can find basically restates the same thing.

```
   -r[-|0]
          Recurse subdirectories (CAUTION: this flag does not do what  you
          think, avoid using it)
```

So, what *does* it do, and why does the author of this documentation think I think it does something else?

This is 7zip 9.04 on Debian Squeeze (i.e. pretty old).

Comment: Weird. I use the -r switch all the time. Does what it should. I'm using 7-Zip 9.20 on Windows. The documentation that comes with 9.20 doesn't mention anything about avoiding this switch.

Comment: They have a forum where you can post questions. I think you're more likely to get an answer by emailing the author... http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/

Comment: @misha256. It really does not do what you think it does. Please see my answer below as it's quite an odd behaviour that you won't even notice except for a few edge cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the 7-Zip user manual (chm)

Specifies the method of treating wildcards and filenames on the command line.

[image]

Comment: 7-zip.org doesn't have links to the CHM files, but I found a copy of this at http://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/recurse.htm

Comment: It is included with the program after you install it.

Comment: Yes, I get it in `/usr/share/doc/p7zip-full/DOCS/MANUAL` on Debian, but I can't link to that.  A screenshot is not searchable or copy/pasteable so I wanted to include a link before accepting this answer: feel free to include it in the answer itself, obviously.

Comment: We use images here due to link rot.

Answer (score 1):

I never fully understood what `7z.exe` was doing with the `-r` flag until today, and believe this is the correct answer and the meaning behind the authors cryptic note.

In my script using `7z.exe` I was using `-r` a lot until I discovered that an archive had a bunch of subfolders (but I had specified none!). Then I realised that for one of the files that I specified on the command line, `7z.exe` decided to look in all subfolders adjacent to the location that my files are. Although I had specified no folders in my target files, `7z.exe` decided to look in all subfolders and found some files with the same name deeply nested in one of those folders. You can see that it is doing this by the text "Scanning the drive" and it traverses all subfolders before performing the zip. The solution is to only ever use `-r0` - as long as you specify any mix of folders / filenames and *no wildcards*, it will *still* recursively add any folder objects that you specify, but will no longer try to scan the entire filesystem around/beside the current location. I believe that this is what the author meant by "this flag does not do what you think, avoid using it".